# How to create different Column Types in SharePoint Online using PowerShell cmdlets

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I'm using below script that actually create the News List in my SharePoint Online site, but I'm stuck on how to create different Column (Field) types under that List, right now it's just creating a Multiple lines of text Type field (`NewsSum` and `NewsText`). See the script below. I like to create `DateTime` type, `Yes/No` Choice Type, `Multi Selection` Type etc.. fields. Please guide.

```
$newsListName = "News"
Add-List -listTitle $newsListName
[string[][]]$fields =   ("NewsSum","Note",""),
                        ("NewsText","Note","")
Add-FieldsToList $fields $newsListName
```

Comment: Do you have any documentation how to find `Add-List` ? I can't see any such cmdlets in msdn.

Comment: Yup, it's right here, just add this module and you will get that https://sharepointpowershell.codeplex.com/

Comment: just download the above codeplex project, open the example file and search for "Create news list", I'm able to create this, but need to figure out how to create other types, if I change String to DateTime is says, Can Not convert the value NewsSum to System.DateTime.

Comment: Ok I have found. Make sure the list is deleted before you create. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following are the supported FieldTypes you can use

```
Note
DateTime
Currency
Number
Choice
Person or Group
Calculated
```

Example

```
[string[][]]$fields = ("MyChoices","Choice","Left;Right"),("MyNumber","Number","")
```

Comment: wao, you the man.

Comment: Thanks, Just one question, how I create a Single line Text, Like Title field, I can create Note, But I don't see that is supported?